# Align \max operator and \text in optimization problem specification

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

A mysterious space is inserted before the *max* operator, breaking the alignment in the process.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    
\begin{align*}
  &\max c_i \\
  &\text{subject to:} \\
  &\quad v^{\top}_i v_i = 1 \\
  &\quad v^{\top}_i v_j = 0 \ \forall j < i
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\max` builds a math operator. The rules of TeX specify that a between an ordinary symbol and math operator a thin space is inserted; this is wanted in cases such as

```
 $a\log x$
```

which produces

[image]

where the absence of the thin space would give a wrong result.

The `align` and `align*` environments make pairs of columns, the first with right alignment and the second with left alignment. Since the most common case for using them is something like

```
\begin{align}
x &= y \\
a &= b
\end{align}
```

an empty ordinary symbol is implicitly added after the alignment point, so the equals sign (or in general a relation symbol) is correctly spaced. In your case you get the equivalent of the inline formula

```
${}\max c_i$
```

Since an empty group `{}` is considered as an ordinary symbol, you get a thin space.

Possible solution: add `\!` before `\max`, that cancels this thin space.

Better solution: use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
  \max c_i \\
  \textnormal{subject to:} \\
  \quad v^{\top}_i v_i = 1 \\
  \quad v^{\top}_i v_j = 0, \quad \forall j < i
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An environment form that simplifies the input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newenvironment{optimize}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \quad\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
  \hspace{-1em}#1\\
  \hspace{-1em}\textnormal{subject to:}\\}
 {\end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{optimize}{\max c_i}
v^{\top}_i v_i = 1 \\
v^{\top}_i v_j = 0, \quad \forall j < i
\end{optimize}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in this situation, everything looks (almost) aligned. but since the `$i$` and `$j$` are just slightly different widths, in fact the equals signs are *not* aligned.  what should one do if these subscripts are of radically different widths?  (which would visually de-align the last two lines.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think the alignment is necessary, in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The macro `\max` is of type "Math Operator" (mathop for short), meaning that is preceded by a `\thinspace` if the math atom ahead of `\max` is of type "Math Ordinary" (mathord for short); the `align` environment automatically inserts an empty math atom of type mathord after the alignment point, and that's how you end up with the (unwanted) space.

The code below shows four possible remedies; the easiest one may consist of inserting `\!` (negative thinspace) immediately before `\max`.

---

*Addendum*: To avoid getting the subscripts in the items before `^{\top}` to be placed lower than the ones following the transpose sign, it's useful to define a macro called, say, `\trans`. See the code and the screenshot for its implementation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\trans{\!{}^{\top}\!} % insert transpose symbol
\begin{document}    
\begin{align*}
  &\!\max c_i\\
  &\text{max}\, c_i \\
  &\mathord{\max}\, c_i\\
  &\mathopen{}\max c_i\\
  &\text{subject to} \\
  &\quad v_i \trans v_i = 1 \\
  &\quad v_i \trans v_j = 0 \ \forall\ j < i
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps technically appropriate is that mathop uses `\thinmuskip`. So, a correction of `\mskip-\thinmuskip` also works.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks. The LaTeX kernel provides the instruction `\def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}`. Thus, happily, the first remedy listed in the answer is identical to the one you propose.